# Select count(*) vs Select * execution in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a WHERE NOT EXISTS query that basically looks like the following:

```
select count(*)
from TableA a
where not exists (Select 1 from TableB b where a.ID = b.ID);
```

TableA has about 8562212 records, same as TableB

When I run that above query it runs indefinitely. When I replace

```
select count(*)
```

with just

```
select *
```

the query runs in 2 secs and returns 0 rows (as expected).  Also when I run the reverse where not exists (TableB where not exists....TableA), using count(*) it runs in 2 secs and returns 0 rows.

The only issue is that query above.  I will add that I have run similar queries on many many DB tables and never run into this issue. Any ideas why this may be happening?  I am stumped.  Thanks

Comment: both tables likely need primary indexes based on the id columns

Comment: Can you post the Explains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a left join ?

```
select count(*)
from TableA a
LEft join TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
where b.ID is null
```

Comment: That works.  I ended up using a MINUS query and wrapping a count(*) around that, just to get around this particular table comparison.  All others work fine. So weird.  Thanks

Comment: I usually use left join instead of not exists query, I am glad that it worked for you.